# Arranging/filtering 3 columns of data in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file (see the picture) for which I want to specifically arrange my data.

What I want is "col1" to be arranged from the most past date, so 5/1/2016 then 5/2/2016 and so on. With that, I want "col2" to have everything in alphabetical ascending order, and the dates in "col3" to be just like in "col1". The key column is "col1" meaning everything needs to based on that.

I did it manually, but I can't do that with 1000 lines in excel.

[image: Excel file picture]

Answer (score 0):

It should suffice to just do this:

1. Sort *col3* ascending
2. Sort *col2* ascending
3. Sort *col1* ascending

*(sorting is done in the* Data *ribbon by clicking the* A-Z *button)*

Since the sorting algorithm that is employed by Excel is *stable*, the existing order is kept for entries with the same value. Thus sorting multiple times on different columns in the reverse order you mentioned should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *custom sort* function in **sort & filter**. Then you can add levels

[image]

Comment: This can actually be simplified by just clicking the sorting button for each column as I stated in my answer. No need for a custom sort.